# Rails model belongs to model that belongs to model but i want to use another name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

This may be a stupid question but im just starting to learn Rail thats why i am asking thsi question.

I have one model called "User" which handles all the users in my community. Now i want to add a guestbook to every user. So i created a model called "user_guestbook" and inserted this into the new model:

```
belongs_to :user
```

and this into the user model:

```
has_one :user_guestbook, :as => :guestbook
```

The next thing i did was to add a new model to handle the posts inside the guestbook. I named it "guestbook_posts" and added this code into the new model:

```
belongs_to :user_guestbook
```

And this into the user_guestbook model:

```
has_many :guestbook_posts, :as => :posts
```

What i wanted to achive was to be able to fetch all the posts to a certain user by:

```
@user = User.find(1)
puts @user.guestbook.posts
```

But it doesnt work for me. I dont know what i am doing wrong and if there is any easier way to do this please tell me so.

Just to note, i have created some migrations for it to as follows:

create_user_guestbook:

```
  t.integer :user_id
```

create_guestbook_posts:

```
  t.integer :guestbook_id
  t.integer :from_user
  t.string :post
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That it is a undefined method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
#user
has_one :guestbook, :class_name => "UserGuestbook"

#user_guestbook
belongs_to :user
has_many :posts, :class_name => "GuestbookPost"

#guestbook_posts
belongs_to :user_guestbook
```

To get all posts that belongs to a single `user`, you can add this line to the `user`'s model

```
has_many :posts, :through => :guestbook
```

And then, call this:

```
@user.posts
```

Comment: I'm getting "can't convert class into strin" when doing @user = User.find 1 and then @user.guestbook

Comment: The code missed quoted around the value of `class_name`. Try the updated code.